# Using R functions as a list

Tags: r, anonymous-function

I am creating an R list comprising of few functions as :

```
funs <- list(
+     sum = sum,
+     mean = mean,
+     median = median
+     )
```

In order to use lapply, the Hadley Wickham's book that i am referring to uses :

```
lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
```

I do get the first argument of lapply function is list, but how come `function(f) f(x)`
serves to be the the second argument of lapply, which should be a function ideally. My x is:

```
x <- 1:10
```

Comment: @RonakShah, how is it getting evaluated is my concern. I know about anonymous function and hence tagged the question under the same category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it gets clearer when you assign the anonymous function to a name `g`

```
g <- function(f) { 
  f(x)
}
```

`g` has a function as parameter and will call this function with the argument `x`, that is obtained from the lexical scope. So for `x <- 1:10` you get

```
g(sum) # = sum(x) = sum(1:10) 
[1] 55
```

And similarly

```
lapply(funs, g) # = list(g(sum), g(means), g(median)
                # = list(sum(x), means(x), median(x)
                # = list(sum(1:10), means(1:10), median(1:10)
$sum
[1] 55

$mean
[1] 5.5

$median
[1] 5.5
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Harald.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `lapply` is

```
function(f) f(x)
```

which *is* a function. It's a function whose argument is also a function, `f`.

To elucidate what's happening, let's take out the "anonymous" from anonymous function:

```
getFunc <- function(f) f(x)
lapply(funs, getFunc)
```

This is exactly the same as

```
lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
```

without having to define `getFunc` separately.

Going further, let's take out the `x`:

```
getFunc <- function(f, xx) f(xx)
lapply(funs, getFunc, xx=x)
```

This is the same as

```
lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
```

but explicitly passing in the numbers on which to compute the sum, mean and median, rather than automagically getting them from the global environment.

Comment: If x is 1:10, what does this function evaluate to ?

Comment: Run it and find out?

Comment: The output I get is :

`> lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
$sum
[1] 55

$mean
[1] 5.5

$median
[1] 5.5
`
Which I understand. What I dont get is how the second argument, which is a function is getting evaluated and getting passed to lapply.

Comment: lapply is passing the inputs in the list *to* the second argument.  So it's basically saying "let's take the first item in the list and use it as the input for that second argument, now let's take the second item in the list and use it as input for that second argument, ... and so on.

Comment: @HongOoi, so for ex : if my anonymous function is `function(x) x + 5`, then whatever is x, my function adds 5 to my x. Similarly, how does function(f) f(x) work on my x, which happens to be 1:10

Comment: The answer to that is, it does whatever `f` does. Think on that.